# Landscape Saas Firewall ports

Tags: firewall, landscape

I have a quick question regarding Ubuntu Landscape. We are using Landscape as Saas product provided by canonical and it works great.

All of our computers are registered and connected to the landscape, but now we want to add firewall in our network. Therefore we would like to know what ports need to be open on ubuntu servers to keep a constant connection with landscape cloud.

And can we also get somehow the IP addresses of Landscape servers which we can whitelist on our edge firewall?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Landscape Client installed on your Ubuntu hosts communicates with Landscape canonical SaaS servers over `80` and `443` ports.

You need to open `80` and `443` ports for landscape.canonical.com IP addresses which are `91.189.90.173` and `91.189.89.90` (as of now).

In case in future canonical changes servers for landscape SaaS service, You need to update that in your firewall. You can always check ip address of landscape.canonical.com using below command.

```
nslookup landscape.canonical.com
```